# React native webview vs swift/java webview

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, react-native

I am trying to work with developers who have given me answers I an not really sure of. And I lack any experience to judge the answers.

Is the look and feel of `react native webview` much different from look and feel of `swift/java webview` ?

Also is the performance different between the two also?

I did find a similar post on github but it was not answered.

Answer (score 2):

Since react native uses the underlying operating system's inbuilt components, Webview on react native should look like Swift/Java webview depending on where the app is running. Visually there should be no difference.

On a more technical level React Natives webview may not expose all the APIs that a native webview does and React Native may have changed or extended the functionality of the regular webview so it is possible that the functioning of React Natives webview is different than it's native counterparts.

As far as performance I'm not sure but I suppose the above argument of react native modifying things could hold for that as well.